# Set/map of sets represented as an array of ranges into an array - minimizing the size?

Tags: algorithm

I have a map of sets, say

```
a => {cow, dog}, b => {dog}
```

and want to store it as a map of ranges into an array, like

```
a => (start: 0, end: 1), b => (start: 2, end: 2) 
[cow, dog, dog]
```

except of course

```
a => (start: 0, end: 1), b => (start: 1, end: 1)
[cow, dog]
```

would be a more efficient representation. How to find the smallest solution in general? It strikes me as something that would be known to more studied people but searching yields endless pages of vaguely related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I have some highly incomplete thoughts on your problem that are too long to form a comment.

In your example, your solution relies on the fact that

```
P1 = {cow}
P2 = {dog}
```

are the minimal disjoint sets, and that every set is a (disjoint) union of these:

```
S1 = union(P1,P2)
S2 = P2
```

A more complicated example might add a pig and a duck, with three sets

```
S1 = {cow,dog,pig}
S2 = {dog,pig}
S3 = {cow,duck}
```

The corresponding minimal disjoint sets are

```
P1 = {cow}
P2 = {dog,pig}
P3 = {duck}
```

in terms of which

```
S1 = union(P1,P2)
S2 = P2
S3 = union(P1,P3)
```

**Prop.** In general, the elements of any finite collection of sets `C = {S1,S2,...}` can be broken down into a minimal disjoint partition, such that each set in the collection is a disjoint union of a number of collected elements.

*Proof* The universe of all elements is `U = union(S : S in C)`. Then, the complete partition into all elements `P_trivial = {{e} : e in U}` is such a (non-minimal) disjoint partition. Since the set of all such disjoint partitions is non-empty, and since their sizes are finite, there exists one (not necessarily unique) with minimal size, by the well-ordering principle.

*Task #1* To compute this most efficient disjoint partition. A suggested place to start would be finding the intersection and complement of each pair of sets, and building up from these.

Now that an efficient disjoint partition of the elements is in hand, each set is of the form

```
S_i = union(P_j : P_j in partition such that contains(i,j)
```

where `contains(i,j)` is the binary predicate stating that the set `S_i` constains the partition set `P_j`. You can thinking of `contains(i,j)` as forming a matrix with number of rows equal to number of sets and number of columns equal to the number of partitions. In the cow/dog example,

```
contains = 1 1 0
           0 1 0
           1 0 1
```

Note that no two columns of this matrix are equal. If column j1 were equal to column j2, then a set would include the partition element `P_j1` <=> if contained `P_j2`, and so joining `P_j1` and `P_j2` would be a more efficient partition. (Perhaps this is a better way of finding the minimal partition, starting from the trivial partition).

The closer two columns are in contents, the more it makes sense to place the corresponding partition elements together in the array. The definition of "close" could be just the number of rows for which the two columns are equal (i.e. the number of sets that both contain, or do not contain, these partition elements). That will lead to a lot of ties, and it might make sense to weight this by the number of elements in the partition element.

Applying this simple distance metric (ignoring the weights) to pairs of columns leads to a "closeness" matrix. For the cow/dog example, this would be

```
3 1 2
1 3 0
2 0 3
```

A pseudo-equation for this "closeness" matrix could be

```
Closeness = Contains^T (&) Contains
```

i.e. a bitand version of matrix multiplication.

Partition elements should appear consecutively in the array if they are "close" together. For this given matrix, this suggests the order

```
[P2 P1 P3] = [dog, pig, cow, duck]
```

In terms of this array,

```
S1 = range 0 to 2
S2 = range 0 to 1
S3 = range 2 to 3
```

I got this by picking the largest non-diagonal entry in the matrix -- 2, corresponding to P1 and P3, sticking them together. Then, I looked to see whether P2 was closer to P1 or P3, and stuck it on the side it was closer to. Granted, I have not written this as a complete algorithm or proven any sort of minimality, but I believe it might generalize: pick the largest non-diagonal element, put the two corresponding partition elements next to each other, and then chain the remaining partition elements to either side.